# how to make notifications & live online by mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

how to make notifications & live online by mvc?
i'm use $.ajax() by jquery.
example:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
   $.ajax({
       url: "",
       type: "GET",
       data: {},
       success: function (data) {

       }
   })
},1000);
```

Do you the process of sending requests to a server by $. Ajax frequent by Timer affects on the server or database?

Comment: you can use long polling saves resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is better that use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it
>   incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your
>   applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability
>   to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as
>   it happens, in real-time.
>
> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables
>   bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR
>   will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and
>   gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it
>   isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server
>   to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers
>   from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as
>   adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect
>   events, grouping connections, authorization.

Comment: I want create like stackoverflow notifications.

Comment: I think u can use polling or ajax request for get update server like twitter every 30 second and don't worry about server response but if you use signalr u have very feature.